# Zend_Registry not working! set and get

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend MVC Application. I set other variables to Zend Registry previously in the app and it is working perfectly fine. However this time it is not working. While I call the action setmanuel the script echos test. However calling get manuel through a second request i get a script warning telling me that manuel is not set in the registry. I'm fooling around for hours now. It's driving me insane. Why is Zend_Registry not saving my values?

```
public function setmanuelAction(){
    Zend_Registry::set("manuel","test");
    $manu = Zend_Registry::get("manuel");
    echo $manu;
}
public function getmanuelAction(){
    $manu = Zend_Registry::get("manuel");
    echo $manu;
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess I'm just overworked. I need to save it to session not registry ...

Comment: It saves but only per request. In *a second request* it's gone. You need session then, that is across requests. - Edit: Was typing while you posted your comment, so you have some sort of feedback now ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is sessions (here namely probably `Zend_Session`). A registry is always valid during a single request. On any subsequent request the registry is completely independent from the former ones.